# How Firewall bocks ports

Tags: firewall, tcp

When we say firewall has blocked port 28 doest it mean that a firewall process running on a computer scans every packet it receives and if it finds a packet containing port 28 (since packet contains port information) it will not pass that packet  on to particular service listening on port 28

Answer (score 1):

Firewalls examine every packet coming in (and often going out).  If the firewall rules dictate that the packet should be blocked, then it is not passed on.  What "passed on" means depends on the context.  On an end-point machine, the packet is not sent to the application handling the network traffic.  On a router or firewall appliance, the packet is not sent on the output link.

The firewall can completely drop the packet, or if it is TCP connection packet it can ACK the packet then send a reset:

> Rational for dropping packets:
>   If you run no internet facing services, dropping packets instead of rejecting them (RST,ACK) allows you to make your machine to appear to be offline to attackers (as long as you block pings etc). If you run services on uncommon (high range) ports, dropping packets on closed ports can make an attacker overlook you as they may not scan the higher ranges. However, if you run services on common ports and most ports drop packets while these ports reject them, you are actually giving information about what services your system runs. So drop on all ports or don't bother. [Link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=156863)